# Linq to XML Parsing WMS Capabilities Document

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I'm really new to LINQ and I'm having trouble parsing an xml file. The file is this ->

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE WMT_MS_Capabilities SYSTEM "http://schemas.opengis.net/wms/1.1.1/capabilities_1_1_1.dtd"
><WMT_MS_Capabilities version="1.1.1">
 <Service>
  <Name>OGC:WMS</Name>
  <Title>Minnesota composite aerial photography</Title>
  <OnlineResource xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="http://geoint.lmic.state.mn.us/"/>
 </Service>
 <Capability>
  <Request>
   <GetCapabilities>
    <Format>application/vnd.ogc.wms_xml</Format>
    <DCPType>
     <HTTP>
      <Get>
       <OnlineResource xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="http://geoint.lmic.state.mn.us/cgi-bin/mncomp"/>
      </Get>
     </HTTP>
    </DCPType>
   </GetCapabilities>
   <GetMap>
    <Format>image/jpeg</Format>
    <DCPType>
     <HTTP>
      <Get>
       <OnlineResource xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="http://geoint.lmic.state.mn.us/cgi-bin/mncomp"/>
      </Get>
     </HTTP>
    </DCPType>
   </GetMap>
  </Request>
  <Exception>
   <Format>application/vnd.ogc.se_xml</Format>
  </Exception>
  <Layer>
   <Title>Minnesota composite aerial photography</Title>
   <SRS>EPSG:26915</SRS>
   <Style>
    <Name>default</Name>
    <Title>Normal</Title>
    <Abstract>Colors as in original imagery</Abstract>
   </Style>
   <Style>
    <Name>stretch</Name>
    <Title>Contrast Stretch</Title>
    <Abstract>Two standard deviation contrast stretch</Abstract>
   </Style>
   <Layer queryable="0" opaque="1">
    <Name>mncomp</Name>
    <Title>Minnesota Composite Imagery</Title>
    <SRS>EPSG:26915</SRS>
    <LatLonBoundingBox minx="-102.05" miny="40.46" maxx="-85.90" maxy="51.37"/>
    <BoundingBox SRS="EPSG:26915" minx="-131108.45" miny="4505093.25" maxx="994071.55" maxy="5715117.75" resx="28.5" resy="28.5"/>
    <MetadataURL type="FGDC">
     <Format>text/html</Format>
     <OnlineResource xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="http://www.mngeo.state.mn.us/chouse/metadata/naip09.html"></OnlineResource>
    </MetadataURL>
   <ScaleHint min="11.40" max="40334"/>
   </Layer>
   </Layer>
 </Capability>
</WMT_MS_Capabilities>
```

I have a class called "Layer". For each layer in the XML, I want to add the name, title, and the subsequent styles(name tag) related to it to a new Layer object.

This is what I have so far.

```
public class Layer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string SRS { get; set; }

    public List<string> Styles = new List<string>();
}
```

Query

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(localFilename);


var layers = from p in xdoc.Descendants("Layer")
             select new Layer
             {

                 Name = p.Element("Name").Value,
                 Title = p.Element("Title").Value,
                 SRS = p.Element("SRS").Value,
                 //Styles = //How do I get the list of styles for each layer?,
             };
```

This compiles fine with my other code. When I run my application, I get a object reference not set to an instance of an object error. I think it's because there isn't a name element for one of the layers. I don't want to ask two questions in one post so I'll just work out the null checking somehow, but any suggestions on extracting the information from the XML to my object? Thanks in advance. Sorry if my question is not as straightforward as it needs to be, I'm new to the online question asking thing.

@Sergey Berezovskiy your solution works just fine for this specific XML document. For some reason I'm not having the same luck with another XML. Since I'll be hitting different servers I need to make sure it works across the board. Any insight as to why I can extract layers from that xml file, but not the one below? Thank you so much.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<WMS_Capabilities version="1.3.0"
  xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wms"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:esri_wms="http://www.esri.com/wms"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wms http://schemas.opengis.net/wms/1.3.0/capabilities_1_3_0.xsd http://www.esri.com/wms http://www.orthos.dhses.ny.gov/arcgis/services/Latest/MapServer/WMSServer?version=1.3.0&amp;service=WMS&amp;request=GetSchemaExtension">
  <Service>
    <Name><![CDATA[WMS]]></Name>
    <Title><![CDATA[Latest]]></Title>
    <Abstract>WMS</Abstract>
    <KeywordList><Keyword><![CDATA[]]></Keyword></KeywordList>
    <OnlineResource xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="http://www.orthos.dhses.ny.gov/arcgis/services/Latest/MapServer/WMSServer"/>
    <ContactInformation>
      <ContactPersonPrimary>
        <ContactPerson><![CDATA[]]></ContactPerson>
        <ContactOrganization><![CDATA[]]></ContactOrganization>
      </ContactPersonPrimary>
      <ContactPosition><![CDATA[]]></ContactPosition>
      <ContactAddress>
        <AddressType><![CDATA[]]></AddressType>
        <Address><![CDATA[]]></Address>
        <City><![CDATA[]]></City>
        <StateOrProvince><![CDATA[]]></StateOrProvince>
        <PostCode><![CDATA[]]></PostCode>
        <Country><![CDATA[]]></Country>
      </ContactAddress>
      <ContactVoiceTelephone><![CDATA[]]></ContactVoiceTelephone>
      <ContactFacsimileTelephone><![CDATA[]]></ContactFacsimileTelephone>
      <ContactElectronicMailAddress><![CDATA[]]></ContactElectronicMailAddress>
    </ContactInformation>
    <Fees><![CDATA[]]></Fees>
    <AccessConstraints><![CDATA[]]></AccessConstraints>
    <MaxWidth>2048</MaxWidth>
    <MaxHeight>2048</MaxHeight>
  </Service>
  <Capability>
    <Request>
      <GetCapabilities>
        <Format>application/vnd.ogc.wms_xml</Format>
        <Format>text/xml</Format>
        <DCPType>
          <HTTP><Get><OnlineResource xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="http://www.orthos.dhses.ny.gov/arcgis/services/Latest/MapServer/WMSServer"/></Get></HTTP>
        </DCPType>
      </GetCapabilities>
      <GetMap>
        <Format>image/bmp</Format>
        <Format>image/jpeg</Format>
        <Format>image/tiff</Format>
        <Format>image/png</Format>
        <Format>image/png8</Format>
        <Format>image/png24</Format>
        <Format>image/png32</Format>
        <Format>image/gif</Format>
        <Format>image/svg+xml</Format>
        <DCPType>
          <HTTP><Get><OnlineResource xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="http://www.orthos.dhses.ny.gov/arcgis/services/Latest/MapServer/WMSServer"/></Get></HTTP>
        </DCPType>
      </GetMap>
      <GetFeatureInfo>
        <Format>application/vnd.esri.wms_raw_xml</Format>
        <Format>application/vnd.esri.wms_featureinfo_xml</Format>
        <Format>application/vnd.ogc.wms_xml</Format>
        <Format>text/xml</Format>
        <Format>text/html</Format>
        <Format>text/plain</Format>
        <DCPType>
          <HTTP><Get><OnlineResource xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="http://www.orthos.dhses.ny.gov/arcgis/services/Latest/MapServer/WMSServer"/></Get></HTTP>
        </DCPType>
      </GetFeatureInfo>
      <esri_wms:GetStyles>
        <Format>application/vnd.ogc.sld+xml</Format>
        <DCPType>
          <HTTP><Get><OnlineResource xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="http://www.orthos.dhses.ny.gov/arcgis/services/Latest/MapServer/WMSServer"/></Get></HTTP>
        </DCPType>
      </esri_wms:GetStyles>
    </Request>
    <Exception>
      <Format>application/vnd.ogc.se_xml</Format>
      <Format>application/vnd.ogc.se_inimage</Format>
      <Format>application/vnd.ogc.se_blank</Format>
      <Format>text/xml</Format>
      <Format>XML</Format>
    </Exception>
    <Layer>
      <Title><![CDATA[Layers]]></Title>
<CRS>CRS:84</CRS>
<CRS>EPSG:4326</CRS>
<CRS>EPSG:3857</CRS>
<EX_GeographicBoundingBox><westBoundLongitude>-80.57007947624</westBoundLongitude><eastBoundLongitude>-71.0436841582623</eastBoundLongitude><southBoundLatitude>39.9768836585495</southBoundLatitude><northBoundLatitude>45.5666140920784</northBoundLatitude></EX_GeographicBoundingBox>
<BoundingBox CRS="CRS:84"  minx="-80.57007947624" miny="39.9768836585495" maxx="-71.0436841582623" maxy="45.5666140920784"/>
<BoundingBox CRS="EPSG:4326"  minx="-80.57007947624" miny="39.9768836585495" maxx="-71.0436841582623" maxy="45.5666140920784"/>
<BoundingBox CRS="EPSG:3857"  minx="-8969020.22046862" miny="4862583.64415499" maxx="-7908546.74457592" maxy="5711168.75110067"/>
      <Layer queryable="1">
        <Name>0</Name>
        <Title><![CDATA[2007]]></Title>
        <Abstract><![CDATA[2007]]></Abstract>
<CRS>CRS:84</CRS>
<CRS>EPSG:4326</CRS>
<CRS>EPSG:3857</CRS>
<EX_GeographicBoundingBox><westBoundLongitude>-79.4438365409271</westBoundLongitude><eastBoundLongitude>-71.4767021272613</eastBoundLongitude><southBoundLatitude>40.4072997752793</southBoundLatitude><northBoundLatitude>43.5397759908541</northBoundLatitude></EX_GeographicBoundingBox>
<BoundingBox CRS="CRS:84"  minx="-79.4438365409271" miny="40.4072997752793" maxx="-71.4767021272613" maxy="43.5397759908541"/>
<BoundingBox CRS="EPSG:4326"  minx="-79.4438365409271" miny="40.4072997752793" maxx="-71.4767021272613" maxy="43.5397759908541"/>
<BoundingBox CRS="EPSG:3857"  minx="-8843647.43040006" miny="4925307.70532643" maxx="-7956750.08438922" maxy="5394495.50256152"/>
        <Style>
          <Name>default</Name>
          <Title>0</Title>
          <LegendURL width="0" height="0">
            <Format>image/png</Format>
            <OnlineResource xlink:href="http://www.orthos.dhses.ny.gov/arcgis/services/Latest/MapServer/WMSServer?request=GetLegendGraphic%26version=1.3.0%26format=image/png%26layer=0" xlink:type="simple" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" />
          </LegendURL>
        </Style>
      </Layer>
      <Layer queryable="1">
        <Name>1</Name>
        <Title><![CDATA[2008]]></Title>
        <Abstract><![CDATA[2008]]></Abstract>
<CRS>CRS:84</CRS>
<CRS>EPSG:4326</CRS>
<CRS>EPSG:3857</CRS>
<EX_GeographicBoundingBox><westBoundLongitude>-80.137061507241</westBoundLongitude><eastBoundLongitude>-72.9541406362735</eastBoundLongitude><southBoundLatitude>40.2418907294155</southBoundLatitude><northBoundLatitude>45.3235137050738</northBoundLatitude></EX_GeographicBoundingBox>
<BoundingBox CRS="CRS:84"  minx="-80.137061507241" miny="40.2418907294155" maxx="-72.9541406362735" maxy="45.3235137050738"/>
<BoundingBox CRS="EPSG:4326"  minx="-80.137061507241" miny="40.2418907294155" maxx="-72.9541406362735" maxy="45.3235137050738"/>
<BoundingBox CRS="EPSG:3857"  minx="-8920816.88065531" miny="4901155.6944707" maxx="-8121217.78689084" maxy="5672596.70078496"/>
        <Style>
          <Name>default</Name>
          <Title>1</Title>
          <LegendURL width="0" height="0">
            <Format>image/png</Format>
            <OnlineResource xlink:href="http://www.orthos.dhses.ny.gov/arcgis/services/Latest/MapServer/WMSServer?request=GetLegendGraphic%26version=1.3.0%26format=image/png%26layer=1" xlink:type="simple" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" />
          </LegendURL>
        </Style>
      </Layer>
      <Layer queryable="1">
        <Name>2</Name>
        <Title><![CDATA[2009]]></Title>
        <Abstract><![CDATA[2009]]></Abstract>
<CRS>CRS:84</CRS>
<CRS>EPSG:4326</CRS>
<CRS>EPSG:3857</CRS>
<EX_GeographicBoundingBox><westBoundLongitude>-78.2508704377383</westBoundLongitude><eastBoundLongitude>-72.9360410898466</eastBoundLongitude><southBoundLatitude>40.6557323735188</southBoundLatitude><northBoundLatitude>45.2365820956616</northBoundLatitude></EX_GeographicBoundingBox>
<BoundingBox CRS="CRS:84"  minx="-78.2508704377383" miny="40.6557323735188" maxx="-72.9360410898466" maxy="45.2365820956616"/>
<BoundingBox CRS="EPSG:4326"  minx="-78.2508704377383" miny="40.6557323735188" maxx="-72.9360410898466" maxy="45.2365820956616"/>
<BoundingBox CRS="EPSG:3857"  minx="-8710847.05125945" miny="4961694.11943618" maxx="-8119202.954599" maxy="5658843.70875853"/>
        <Style>
          <Name>default</Name>
          <Title>2</Title>
          <LegendURL width="0" height="0">
            <Format>image/png</Format>
            <OnlineResource xlink:href="http://www.orthos.dhses.ny.gov/arcgis/services/Latest/MapServer/WMSServer?request=GetLegendGraphic%26version=1.3.0%26format=image/png%26layer=2" xlink:type="simple" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" />
          </LegendURL>
        </Style>
      </Layer>
      <Layer queryable="1">
        <Name>3</Name>
        <Title><![CDATA[2010]]></Title>
        <Abstract><![CDATA[2010]]></Abstract>
<CRS>CRS:84</CRS>
<CRS>EPSG:4326</CRS>
<CRS>EPSG:3857</CRS>
<EX_GeographicBoundingBox><westBoundLongitude>-78.8352781843513</westBoundLongitude><eastBoundLongitude>-71.5135529969056</eastBoundLongitude><southBoundLatitude>40.3408670985968</southBoundLatitude><northBoundLatitude>43.5222862097287</northBoundLatitude></EX_GeographicBoundingBox>
<BoundingBox CRS="CRS:84"  minx="-78.8352781843513" miny="40.3408670985968" maxx="-71.5135529969056" maxy="43.5222862097287"/>
<BoundingBox CRS="EPSG:4326"  minx="-78.8352781843513" miny="40.3408670985968" maxx="-71.5135529969056" maxy="43.5222862097287"/>
<BoundingBox CRS="EPSG:3857"  minx="-8775903.02402806" miny="4915600.50131933" maxx="-7960852.30443332" maxy="5391810.05477954"/>
        <Style>
          <Name>default</Name>
          <Title>3</Title>
          <LegendURL width="0" height="0">
            <Format>image/png</Format>
            <OnlineResource xlink:href="http://www.orthos.dhses.ny.gov/arcgis/services/Latest/MapServer/WMSServer?request=GetLegendGraphic%26version=1.3.0%26format=image/png%26layer=3" xlink:type="simple" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" />
          </LegendURL>
        </Style>
      </Layer>
      <Layer queryable="1">
        <Name>4</Name>
        <Title><![CDATA[2011]]></Title>
        <Abstract><![CDATA[2011]]></Abstract>
<CRS>CRS:84</CRS>
<CRS>EPSG:4326</CRS>
<CRS>EPSG:3857</CRS>
<EX_GeographicBoundingBox><westBoundLongitude>-79.4439599225417</westBoundLongitude><eastBoundLongitude>-72.9501226871704</eastBoundLongitude><southBoundLatitude>41.8707392833946</southBoundLatitude><northBoundLatitude>44.5521070703263</northBoundLatitude></EX_GeographicBoundingBox>
<BoundingBox CRS="CRS:84"  minx="-79.4439599225417" miny="41.8707392833946" maxx="-72.9501226871704" maxy="44.5521070703263"/>
<BoundingBox CRS="EPSG:4326"  minx="-79.4439599225417" miny="41.8707392833946" maxx="-72.9501226871704" maxy="44.5521070703263"/>
<BoundingBox CRS="EPSG:3857"  minx="-8843661.16517858" miny="5141636.43859296" maxx="-8120770.51084265" maxy="5551283.37379781"/>
        <Style>
          <Name>default</Name>
          <Title>4</Title>
          <LegendURL width="0" height="0">
            <Format>image/png</Format>
            <OnlineResource xlink:href="http://www.orthos.dhses.ny.gov/arcgis/services/Latest/MapServer/WMSServer?request=GetLegendGraphic%26version=1.3.0%26format=image/png%26layer=4" xlink:type="simple" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" />
          </LegendURL>
        </Style>
      </Layer>
      <Layer queryable="1">
        <Name>5</Name>
        <Title><![CDATA[2012]]></Title>
        <Abstract><![CDATA[2012]]></Abstract>
<CRS>CRS:84</CRS>
<CRS>EPSG:4326</CRS>
<CRS>EPSG:3857</CRS>
<EX_GeographicBoundingBox><westBoundLongitude>-80.0942239470773</westBoundLongitude><eastBoundLongitude>-73.3855444518878</eastBoundLongitude><southBoundLatitude>40.3409427412789</southBoundLatitude><northBoundLatitude>43.5208041873471</northBoundLatitude></EX_GeographicBoundingBox>
<BoundingBox CRS="CRS:84"  minx="-80.0942239470773" miny="40.3409427412789" maxx="-73.3855444518878" maxy="43.5208041873471"/>
<BoundingBox CRS="EPSG:4326"  minx="-80.0942239470773" miny="40.3409427412789" maxx="-73.3855444518878" maxy="43.5208041873471"/>
<BoundingBox CRS="EPSG:3857"  minx="-8916048.22527106" miny="4915611.54885857" maxx="-8169241.4399713" maxy="5391582.5351876"/>
        <Style>
          <Name>default</Name>
          <Title>5</Title>
          <LegendURL width="0" height="0">
            <Format>image/png</Format>
            <OnlineResource xlink:href="http://www.orthos.dhses.ny.gov/arcgis/services/Latest/MapServer/WMSServer?request=GetLegendGraphic%26version=1.3.0%26format=image/png%26layer=5" xlink:type="simple" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" />
          </LegendURL>
        </Style>
      </Layer>
      <Layer queryable="1">
        <Name>6</Name>
        <Title><![CDATA[2013]]></Title>
        <Abstract><![CDATA[2013]]></Abstract>
<CRS>CRS:84</CRS>
<CRS>EPSG:4326</CRS>
<CRS>EPSG:3857</CRS>
<EX_GeographicBoundingBox><westBoundLongitude>-74.7479376518685</westBoundLongitude><eastBoundLongitude>-71.6430956456583</eastBoundLongitude><southBoundLatitude>40.4458244329041</southBoundLatitude><northBoundLatitude>42.5823674302754</northBoundLatitude></EX_GeographicBoundingBox>
<BoundingBox CRS="CRS:84"  minx="-74.7479376518685" miny="40.4458244329041" maxx="-71.6430956456583" maxy="42.5823674302754"/>
<BoundingBox CRS="EPSG:4326"  minx="-74.7479376518685" miny="40.4458244329041" maxx="-71.6430956456583" maxy="42.5823674302754"/>
<BoundingBox CRS="EPSG:3857"  minx="-8320902.35725337" miny="4930941.35317504" maxx="-7975272.92612848" maxy="5248618.41994531"/>
        <Style>
          <Name>default</Name>
          <Title>6</Title>
          <LegendURL width="0" height="0">
            <Format>image/png</Format>
            <OnlineResource xlink:href="http://www.orthos.dhses.ny.gov/arcgis/services/Latest/MapServer/WMSServer?request=GetLegendGraphic%26version=1.3.0%26format=image/png%26layer=6" xlink:type="simple" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" />
          </LegendURL>
        </Style>
      </Layer>
    </Layer>
  </Capability>
</WMS_Capabilities>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some `Layer` elements do not have `Name` child. Thus `p.Element("Name")` returns `null`. And you have `NullReferenceException` when trying to get its value `p.Element("Name").Value`.

It's easy to fix if you will use casting instead of accessing `Value` property (casting to string will return `null` if element not found, without throwing exception):

```
var layers = from l in xdoc.Descendants("Layer")
             select new Layer
             {
                 Name = (string)l.Element("Name"),
                 Title = (string)l.Element("Title"),
                 SRS = (string)l.Element("SRS"),
                 Styles = l.Elements("Style")
                           .Select(s => (string)s.Element("Name"))
                           .ToList()
             };
```

NOTE: Thus you have `Styles` as list of strings in your layer class, then I used style name as its value in list.

---

Query returns following two layers:

```
[
  {
    Styles: [ "default", "stretch" ],
    Name: null,
    Title: "Minnesota composite aerial photography",
    SRS: "EPSG:26915"
  },
  {
    Styles: [],
    Name: "mncomp",
    Title: "Minnesota Composite Imagery",
    SRS: "EPSG:26915"
  }
]
```

Comment: Thank you sir. I've added something else to my question above if you care to provide some suggestion.